# Spring 4.3.7 and Hibernate 3.5.6 - org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

We are upgrading spring in our product from 3.2.17 to 4.3.7. However I am getting a hibernate exception : org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()

The solution that is given in various forums is to add the @Generated annotation for the model entity . However this issue started happening only after spring upgrade (no code changes done for model classes)

Has anyone seen similar issue with spring 4.3.7 and hibernate 3.5 . In parallel I am trying to upgrade the hibernate version also which is compatible with spring , but the question is why the spring upgrade is triggering this ID generation issue in hibernate

Appreciate any inputs on this . Thanks!

Rgds
Ujwala

Comment: you have upgraded the software to another major version (the first number has changed). Major versions are often **incompatible**. I suggest you read the change log.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jakub. I  am currently trying  to resolve this by upgrading the hibernate version.